# How to configure an Ionic App with a MEAN stack

Tags: ionic-framework, mean-stack

I'm trying to configure an ionic app with an express server and mongodb database for a personal project. I'm a beginner with this - I've set up and have been working with a MEAN stack outside of the Ionic framework, but have not been able to figure out how to structure the ionic app so that it can run on express and mongodb -- and will be able to emulate properly.

I've searched online, but there doesnt seem to be much out there on this topic. This is the closest I've come to an answer: http://thejackalofjavascript.com/an-end-to-end-hybrid-app/. But it still doesnt help me entirely. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: you do not need to configure an ionic app for a mean stack. Build the app, then use node/express to build your server. The app will make http calls to the server to retrieve/post data. The server will hook up to the mongodb. When you build a mean stack you really have two sides. The front end and the back end. The only thing connecting the two will be http calls. So you will build the server/databse totally separate and different than the front end. I recommenced you buy this book, it helped me get started https://leanpub.com/mean-machine

Comment: The book has everything you need to get started.